# Сохранение данных в Google аккаунте

Tags: android, firebase, google-account

Возможно ли средствами `API Google` сохранить в аккаунте `Google`, например значение игровых монет или настроек, а потом вытащить его оттуда? Если например человек удалит игру, потом снова установит, чтобы все настройки и данные сохранялись в аккаунте.
С `API Google` сделал авторизацию в приложении `android`, а вот данные как сохранить?

И на счет `Firebase`, там можно хранить данные, но там как я понял, есть ограничение на одновременное подключение к базе на бесплатном аккаунте. Вроде число ограничения: 100 чел было, можно ли подключаться, брать данные и отключаться?

И еще, мне нужно использовать их авторизацию (т.е. для пользователей), чтобы подключаться к базе или я могу создать 1 логин, и его использовать у всех пользователей, как авторизацию и брать определенные данные?

Comment: разве сервис google play игры создан не именно для этого (сохранение прогресса игрока), зачем выдумывать что то свое?

Comment: @pavloff сервис google play только и делает что сохраняет прогресс т.е. счет игрока, а количество монет, настройки и т.д. он не сохраняет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Квота на подключение действует на одновременные коннекты(в данную секунду - не более 100 подключений). Это значит, что если человек зашел, сделал свои дела и вышел - его коннект освобождается.
2) Данные в google аккаунт сохранить нельзя, ты можешь сохранить уникальный id(например device token) устройства, сделать кнопочку вроде "восстановить данные" по которым ты будешь на клиента высылать все данные из своей БД(не БД firebase, а именно из БД на твоем сервере). Как вариант,
 можно конечно из своей БД, и не чистить firebase, но тогда на фришном аккаунте у тебя довольно быстро может забиться всё место(в зависимости от размера проекта, конечно)
3)Ты можешь не использовать их авторизацию, если настроишь корректным образом правила БД firebase-а
4)Есть также квота на получение данных из БД, в месяц сколько-то ГБ

Comment: а вот там момент есть, я про ваш 4 пункт, что сколько использовал, столько и платишь. Платить надо раз в месяц? Там цены такие: $5/GB $1/GB, а если я например меньше 1 ГБ использую, я все равно должен заплатить за 1 Гб ? И сколько по вашему будет весить размер 3 строк в таблице, имя аккаунта, количество монет, и еще одно количество монет?

Comment: @Iman вот вам статейка про "сколько использовал, столько и платишь" https://habrahabr.ru/company/everydaytools/blog/329282/

Comment: @Iman К теме сколько используешь - столько платишь. Если вы не будете юзать 1ГБ, лучше не платить. Если вы уверены , что заюзаете весь фришный лимит - берите Blaze, 3 строки в БД на гиг точно не потянут, и трафик за месяц не сьедят, но опять таки, всё только на словах, более приближенные цифры посчитать можете вы, исходя из того, сколько планируется юзеров, сколько планируется обращений к БД и т.д.